# Extreme Latency Using Storage Migration Service

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, robocopy, windows-server-2019

**Issue Summary:**

High latency experienced on LAN when running a Storage Migration Service job -- copy share data from one DC to another. Latency drops **considerably** when using a simple robo script.

**Detail:**

Traditionally, I've used robo scripts, which works like a charm. I have been testing *Windows Admin Center* on a Hyper-V VM running 2019 Server OS. In particular, I've been focusing on *Storage Migration Service*.

Environment:

**DC-02**: Windows Server 2019 with SMS installed.

**WAC (Windows Admin Center VM)**: 2019 OS with WAC installed and running.

**DC-01**: 2008 R2 with all company shares.

The transfer that runs via SMS from DC-01 --> DC-02 brings the LAN to a crawl. Conversely, when I run a robo of all directories, there is largely no impact. I ran a few persistent pings to add color.

The following test shows a clear distinction between no SMS job running v. a job running:

```
Pinging servername.local [IP] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=132ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=210ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=214ms TTL=128
Request timed out.
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=191ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=239ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=206ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=208ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=192ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=214ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=211ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=209ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=213ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=210ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=228ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=224ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=138ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=217ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=225ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=194ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=169ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=226ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=223ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=255ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=203ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=215ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=229ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=224ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=208ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=91ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=193ms TTL=128
```

Not shown in the above is latency later reaching 800ms+. Condensed the results.

The following shows the difference between a robo job running v. a job not running:

```
Pinging servername.local [IP] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=74ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=19ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=96ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=104ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=37ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=40ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=55ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=27ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=28ms TTL=128
Reply from IP: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=128
```

There are not any obvious indicators as to what may be causing the problem. I've read through their KB and relevant hundred plus page documentation. I am in need of a second pair of eyes.

Any thoughts? I prefer Robo, but if SMS goes beyond file migration, which they say it will, it would be nice to use it without bringing everything to a halt.

Comment: The thought of migrating running VMs from one DC to another gives me a headache. Just thinking about all of the moving parts, and how to handle a process' resource requests as half of the things it needs have been moved to the other DC... Granted, I'm sure it'll happen someday if it isn't already, but ow.